# WP undefined WP_CONTENT_DIR

Tags: ajax, wordpress, directory

when i try include a file with ajax i get this error:

*Warning: Use of undefined constant WP_CONTENT_DIR - assumed 'WP_CONTENT_DIR'*

**my dir function:**

```
function mydir(){
    return WP_CONTENT_DIR."/plugins";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WP_CONTENT_DIR` is a constant that WordPress sets up for you during its initialization sequence.

If you are directly accessing a PHP file via AJAX, then likely WordPress is not initialized there, so the constant is undefined, and PHP assumes you must have meant to type a string there instead, leading to the error message.

When you load a file via AJAX, it kicks off a brand new PHP process. If WordPress isn't loaded for that, it can't know things that WordPress knows.

This is why AJAX requests that require access to WordPress resources are designed to be handled in a special way by WordPress. You send requests to a specific URL that WordPress makes available, along with a specified action, and then you define what that action does with a function. Since requests made to *this* URL include starting up WordPress, you have access to whatever you need from WordPress there.

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins